# How to use Select2 Ajax on CakePHP?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, jquery-select2

I have been trying to make an autocomplete dropdown list but I really have no idea on how to do it. I have found an example on youtube but sadly it is not for cakephp. Here is the link if you are curious: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6yCBggCKl0&t=305s. Please help me.

The CakePHP version of the project I'm working with is 3.8.

Here are the code the I come up with so far:

view:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: "<?php echo Router::url(["controller"=>"VScripts","action"=>"searchTask"]); ?>",
                    dataType: "json",
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term,
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: data,
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                placeholder: 'Type atleast 1 digit to search',
                minimumInputLength: 1
            });
```

Controller:

```
public function searchTask()
    {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $term = $this->request->query['q'];
            $select = array(
                'task_id' => 'id',
            );
            $tasksTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Tasks');

            $tasks = $tasksTable
                ->find()
                ->select($select)
                ->from('tasks')
                ->where(['task_id' => '%' . $term . '%'])
                ->limit(10)
                ->order(['task_id' => 'ASC'])
                ->execute()
                ->fetchAll('assoc');

            $result = array();
            foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                $id = $task['task_id'];
                $result[] = array('id' => $id, 'text' => $id);
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: Added `exit` before the end if function after line `echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try it out and get back to ya.

Comment: Tried it out but nothing happened, thank you though.